# C# checked box redundant

Tags: c#, winforms

I have boxes that when checked, I want the button to be true. If all check boxes are unchecked then button is false. Now the problem I'm having is trying to see if their a way to do this all in one code instead of typing it for all boxes. I only included the first 2 boxes since it's the same for all boxes. *I am a noob and this is all from 2-3 days of learning C# from youtube and your forums.*

```
 private void boxChrome_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (boxChrome.Checked == true)
            butInstall.Enabled = true;
        else if
            (boxChrome.Checked == false & boxAdobeReader.Checked == false & boxESET.Checked == false & boxiTunes.Checked == false & boxQuicktime.Checked == false & boxTeamviewer.Checked == false & boxWinrar.Checked == false & boxVLC.Checked == false)
            butInstall.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void boxAdobereader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (boxAdobeReader.Checked == true)
            butInstall.Enabled = true;
        else if
            (boxChrome.Checked == false & boxAdobeReader.Checked == false & boxESET.Checked == false & boxiTunes.Checked == false & boxQuicktime.Checked == false & boxTeamviewer.Checked == false & boxWinrar.Checked == false & boxVLC.Checked == false)
            butInstall.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void butInstall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     }
```

Comment: Please note that the `visual-studio` tag is reserved for questions *about* Visual Studio.  From the tag:  "Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality, not just a question regarding your code"

Comment: Why not have all check boxes fire the same event.  That event then would check all the check boxes it needs to to change the button.

Comment: How would I write that down? Sorry, still new to all of this

Comment: You should learn about WPF data binding, commands, converters, etc. After that you can easily resolve your problem.

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF?

Comment: It is a Winforms

Answer (score 5):

> Now the problem I'm having is trying to see if their a way to do this all in one code instead of typing it for all boxes. I only included the first 2 boxes since it's the same for all boxes.

Your instinct that something is deeply wrong if you are typing the same code multiple times is correct, so good on you for having good instincts.

The way to deal with that is to abstract the code to a method:

```
private void CheckedChanged(CheckBox box)
{
    if (box.Checked == true)
        butInstall.Enabled = true;
    else if
        (boxChrome.Checked == false & 
        boxAdobeReader.Checked == false & 
        boxESET.Checked == false & 
        boxiTunes.Checked == false & 
        boxQuicktime.Checked == false & 
        boxTeamviewer.Checked == false & 
        boxWinrar.Checked == false & 
        boxVLC.Checked == false)
        butInstall.Enabled = false;
}
private void boxChrome_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
  CheckChanged(boxChrome);

private void boxAdobereader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
  CheckChanged(boxAdobeReader);
```

All right.  Can we do better?  Oh good heavens yes.

To begin with:  in C# only newbs say

```
if (box.Checked == true)
```

This means "if it is true that this thing is true, then", which is crazy. Just say "if this thing is true, then"

```
if (box.Checked)
```

If it is true then it is **already true**. You don't need to check to see if it is true that true is equal to true.

Similarly, only newbs say

```
boxChrome.Checked == false
```

If you want to know if something is false, use the `NOT` operator:

```
!boxChrome.Checked
```

All right, so now we have

```
private void CheckedChanged(CheckBox box)
{
    if (box.Checked)
        butInstall.Enabled = true;
    else if (
        !boxChrome.Checked & !boxAdobeReader.Checked & 
        !boxESET.Checked & !boxiTunes.Checked & 
        !boxQuicktime.Checked & !boxTeamviewer.Checked &
        !boxWinrar.Checked & !boxVLC.Checked))
        butInstall.Enabled = false;
}
```

So that's much better.

Can we do better? Sure! We can notice that "are all of these things false?" is the same as "is it false that one of these things is true?"

```
private void CheckedChanged(CheckBox box)
{
    if (box.Checked)
        butInstall.Enabled = true;
    else if (
        !(boxChrome.Checked | boxAdobeReader.Checked | 
        boxESET.Checked | boxiTunes.Checked | 
        boxQuicktime.Checked | boxTeamviewer.Checked |
        boxWinrar.Checked | boxVLC.Checked))
        butInstall.Enabled = false;
}
```

So that's easier to read.  I notice that also you could use `||` instead of `|`, though in this case it really makes very little difference.

Can we do better? Sure. What are we really trying to check here? We're trying to express the notion of "is any box unchecked?" So we could use a LINQ sequence operator to answer that question. Make a field to contain your boxes:

```
private CheckBox[] boxes;
```

In your form load method, initialize the field:

```
...
boxes = { boxChrome, boxAdobeReader, ... }
...
```

and now we can use this:

```
private void CheckedChanged(CheckBox box)
{
    if (box.Checked)
        butInstall.Enabled = true;
    else if (!boxes.Any(box => box.Checked))
        butInstall.Enabled = false;
}
```

Now the code reads like its intention.  **Enable the button if the specific box is checked, otherwise disable it if there is is not any checked box"**.  Try to find a way to make your code read like its intention. It will be shorter, it will be easier to understand, and it will more likely be right.

And always ask yourself "can I do better?"  For example, can we generate the set of checkboxes automatically?  My comment to Vikhram's answer gives a good suggestion.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thank you very much!  It's a great walkthrough of the thought process and different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: This is such a detailed answer and you went out of your way to give me some pointers. Thank you so much sir. I haven't tried it yet but will give this a shot and post my results!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by all `CheckBox`. Let me assume that all the `CheckBox` are directly in the form (as opposed to some other container within the form).

In that case, you can write a generic function like below

```
private static bool IsOneChecked(Control parent) {
    return parent.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(box => box.Checked);
}
```

This function will tell you if at-least one `CheckBox` is checked or not. You can use its return value to enable or disable your `Button` like below

```
butInstall.Enabled = IsOneChecked(this);
```

`this` represents the instance of the container containing all the `CheckBox`. You can adapt it based on how your `Form` is laid`out. In case the`CheckBox`spans multiple containers, you can expand the`IsOneChecked`function to look for all the relevant`CheckBox`

Comment: Sorry the "All check boxes" is all the boxes in the form. Your answer is similar to a form I have found in this site but I could not understand it.

Comment: @infamous what does your comment mean..? if you don't understand it.. then I would suggest that you read up on lambda expressions and understand the Controls Class as well

Comment: Better than `parent.Controls.Cast<Control>().Any(...)` is `parent.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(cb => cb.Checked)`

Comment: You can fix it more. You don't need to have an `is` check inside the lambda if you make it `OfType<CheckBox>`.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks! Fixed it again. That's what happens with a rush job :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem, but here's a thought. Make a list of checkboxes and any time one is updated, update the master checkbox. You can check the list for something that is checked. if you add a checkbox, you just add it to the list.

```
var checkBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
checkBoxes.Add(boxAdobeReader); 
... // add the others. 

private void UpdateMasterCheckBoxState(){ 
   masterButton.IsChecked = checkboxes.Any((cbox) => cbox.IsChecked == true ); 
}

private void anyCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateMasterCheckBoxState();
}
```

then in your xaml, they can all use this handler

```
<CheckBox Click="anyCheckbox_CheckedChanged">AdobeReader</Checkbox>
```

, or if you need different handling for each checkbox they can just call UpdateMasterCheckBoxState() at the end of each handler.

```
private void AdobeCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoAdobeOnlyStuff();
    UpdateMasterCheckBoxState();
}
```